# How can I determine the date of a snapshot in SQL Server 2008r2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, replication, snapshot

I am working on implementing an ETL process to load data into a warehouse.

Part of this process is pulling data from our production server (Server P) to a staging server where the actual load into the warehouse (and the warehouse itself) is located (Server S).  We are using snapshot replication for this.

For QC and some other purposes, I need a way to determine the date that the snapshot was taken on Server P, **from Server S**.  Linking servers for this query I don't think is an option.

I'm hoping that there is a record in a metadata table somewhere to reflect this, or some other command I can run to query the snapshot history.

Answer (score 5):

[`MSSnapshot_History`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180128.aspx) has snapshot information for replication.

You can join to [`MSSnapshot_Agents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188049.aspx) to narrow it down to your specific agent, publication, and job.

These tables are found in the `[distribution]` database on your distribution instance.

Here's a basic query to get the last start time of your snapshot agents.

```
select a.name, max(start_time) laststart
    from MSsnapshot_agents a
        join MSsnapshot_history h 
            on a.id = h.agent_id
            where h.runstatus = 2 -- this will get you the last successful execution
        group by a.name
```

Comment: So this needs to run on the **distributor** but not necessarily on the **subscriber** if they are not the same, correct?

Comment: @JNK yes, sorry. I updated with a bit about where they're found.

Comment: OK, and just to confirm, the `start_time` field is the timestamp of the snapshot in the publisher, correct?

Comment: It is the start time of the agent job. This information is logged by the distribution instance (usually the subscriber).

Comment: So in fact this will show me the time that the distributor agent ran, but NOT the time that the snapshot was taken on the publisher